# Display flash message from router to a ejs view

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I am setting up flash message to be displayed on view whenever the message is sent from the router to the view

```
if (err) {
            console.log(err);
         } else {
            req.flash('success', 'You are now registered and can Log in')
            res.redirect('/users/login');
            // res.render('users/login',{
            //    success_message:'Account created successfully'
            // });
         }
```

is there a way to get this displayed on the view when the page loads without having to do it manually as the one commented, because that one works, but I'd like to get it automatically shown. I have checked some submissions available on the forum, I am still not able to find one that really gets the message displayed

Answer (score 0):

use [connect-flash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-flash) for the session used for storing messages.

```
const flash = require('connect-flash');
```

Use middleware in express js

```
app.use(flash());
```

Append flash message in request render

```
res.render('/users/login', { message: req.flash('Restistration succesfully.') });
```

To show the flash message in html/ejs

```
<% if (message.length > 0) { %>
   <div class="alert alert-danger"><%= message %></div>
 <% } %>
```

Comment: I intended to display flash errors while doing a  `res.redirect` instead of `res.render`. Your solution works, but it is not in the context i wanted

Comment: Try this req.flash('success', 'Restistration succesfully.'); res.redirect('/users/login'); as per document